# Collection object in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

before insert technology jpa in my project, I had an array of object of my data in my db. It functioned normally.

But now that I I use jpa, he told me "null pointer exception"

Here is my first select function

```
public Nodes select(HttpServletRequest request) throws Dao_exception 
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) 
        {
        }

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/akinator";
        String utilisateur = "root";
        String motDePasse = "root";
        Connection connexion = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultset = null;

        try
        {
            connexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection( url, utilisateur, motDePasse );
            statement =  (Statement) connexion.createStatement();
            resultset = (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery(SQL_SELECT);

            List<Nodes> nodeList = new ArrayList<Nodes>();
              while (resultset.next()) 
              {
                  Nodes node = new Nodes( resultset.getLong("id"),
                                          resultset.getString("question"),
                                          resultset.getString("result"),
                                          resultset.getLong("id_left_node_children"),
                                          resultset.getLong("id_right_node_children"));

                 nodeList.add(node);
              }
              nodes = nodeList.toArray(new Nodes[nodeList.size()]);

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nodes[0];
    }
```

and here the same function in jpa

```
public List<Nodes> select (HttpServletRequest request) throws Dao_exception
    {
        List <Nodes> nodeList = new ArrayList<Nodes>();
        nodeList = em.createQuery("SELECT n FROM Nodes n").getResultList();

        return nodeList;
    }
```

here is my servlet

```
@EJB
    private Node_dao nodes_dao;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {       
        Node_dao nodess = new Node_dao();       
        Nodes cursor = new Nodes();

        cursor = nodess.select(request).get(1);

        request.setAttribute("Nodes", cursor);

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response );
    }
```

Here my class Nodes

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "node")
public class Nodes
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id_node;

    @Column (name = "question")
    private String question;

    @Column ( name = "result")
    private String result;

    @Column ( name = "id_left_node_children")
    private Long id_left_node_children;

    @Column ( name = "id_right_node_children")
    private Long id_right_node_children;

    Nodes left;
    Nodes right;

    private final static Map<Long, Nodes> nodes=new HashMap<Long,Nodes>();

    public Nodes(Long id, String question, String result, Long id_left_node_children, Long id_right_node_children) 
    {
           this.id_node=id;
           this.question=question;
           this.result=result;
           this.id_left_node_children=id_left_node_children;
           this.id_right_node_children=id_right_node_children;
           nodes.put(id, this);
    }
```

and my error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.Node_dao.select(Node_dao.java:32)
    at servlet.Game.doGet(Game.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

is what my list is created ?
Thank

Perfect!

But now i have a new error.

Here my new error

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Nodes> to Nodes
    at servlet.Game.doGet(Game.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: can u paste the error stack tracer

Comment: You should tell us where you get your NullPointerException.

Comment: Ho sorry, my null pointer exception is on "nodeList = em.createQuery("SELECT n FROM Nodes n").getResultList();"

Comment: This should not fail. Are you sure that `em` is not null?

Comment: Just check em is not null, other thn this no any object can throw such exeption

Comment: I'm sure because i have a user inscription with the same syntax and it's ok

Comment: Can you show us the class `Nodes` please?

Comment: can u paste the error stack trace

Comment: Paste the complete stack trace of the exception. It matters.

Comment: Sorry, i can't show my class Nodes because is too long

Comment: @Biohazard401 you must edit your question to add the code.

Comment: Sorry, i edit my code

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

`cursor = nodess.select(request).get(1);`

you need to use the EJB, only there the EnitityManager will be available:

`cursor = nodes_dao.select(request).get(1);`